# pyzbar with Python 3.8 does not detect QR-Code in scanned documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, zbar

I am trying to find the QR-Code below with pyzbar 0.1.8 and Python 3.8 on a x64 windows machine. I try to get the QR-Code like this:

```
import cv2
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode, ZBarSymbol

image = cv2.imread('test_04_p1.jpg')
detected_barcodes = decode(image , symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])
```

However nothing is found. Leaving out the symbols definition does not help either. The QR-Code is detecable because when I point my iPhone camera to the screen displaying the sample code it is read successfully. Also [this](https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/) site can find the QR-Code.

What am I doing wrong?

[Sample QR-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU1nK.jpg)